# Visual Studio don't see my device

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows

I writing Windows Phone app for Windows 10

I try to deploy app on my device (Lumia 550)

But it not shown in list of devices.

I turn on developer on my laptop and on phone

How I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: Change the platform from `x86` to `ARM`.

Comment: Still not see my device @GabrielNegut

Answer (score 0):

U are creating an Universal Windows App,
u should create an Windows Phone 8.1 App.

Comment: I downloaded Windows 10 SDK and have only Universal App.

Windows Phone 8.1  is Windows 8.1 SDK

Comment: @LacondeguyBasic so you're using the Windows10 Previews?

Comment: I have Windows 10 on my phone from first start.

Comment: @LacondeguyBasic, okay, is your device visible in your explorer? or did you miss any drivers?

Comment: Yes , it visible in Device Manager.

Comment: Then try it with the windows phone sdk 8.1

Comment: Try it with Windows 8.1 SDK. But it still not see my phone?

Answer (score 0):

Is your device registered as a Developer Device? In the Phone SDK is an App "Windows Phone Deveveloper Registration". You have to enable your device as Developer Device. 
And, yes, your App must be a Universal App for (8.1 or 10, depending on your Phone OS Version).

Regards, 
Oliver

Comment: I don't see developer registration in Windows 10 SDK. I turn on Developer mode on my phone

Answer (score 0):

Another Option, after seeing the Screen shot again. You have to Switch from x86 or x64 to ARM in the Build-Options.

Comment: Don't see. I try to switch.

Comment: Direct left next to the start button, there is a drop down list. There you can select the Processor. Your currently Building for x86.

Comment: I try
don't see my phone

Comment: Okay. I select device and it need PIN. I use Device Descovery on my device and select Pair. I have my Pin, but when I Enter it on Visual Studio, it says that it is incorrect.